# Getting Inner Nested Tag Data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

[image: Image to a nest of tags]

I want to get the information in the inner tag, but it keep returning empty. This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.krak.dk/cafe/s%C3%B8g.cs?consumer=suggest?search_word=cafe"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

genData = soup.find_all("ol", {"class": "hit-list"})
print genData
for infoX in genData:
    print inforX.text
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html is broken, you need a different parser, you can use *lxml* if you have it:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
```

Or use *html5lib*:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
```

*lxml* has dependencies like libxml, *html5lib* can be installed with pip.

```
In [9]: url = "http://www.krak.dk/cafe/s%C3%B8g.cs?consumer=suggest?search_word=cafe"

In [10]: r = requests.get(url)
In [11]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
In [12]: len(soup.find_all("ol", {"class": "hit-list"}))Out[12]: 0

In [13]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
In [14]: len(soup.find_all("ol", {"class": "hit-list"}))
Out[14]: 1

In [15]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

In [16]: len(soup.find_all("ol", {"class": "hit-list"}))
Out[16]: 1
```

There is also only one `hit-list` so you can use find in place of find_all and you can use also use the id `soup.find(id="hit-list")`. If you run the html thorugh the [w3c's html validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.krak.dk%2Fcafe%2Fs%25C3%25B8g.cs%3Fconsumer%3Dsuggest%3Fsearch_word%3Dcafe) you can see there are lots of issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with character encoding utf-8. Since the web page includes special Danish character Åå,Øø,Ææ. Thanks Padraic, I would not have noted about the broken address.

Adding  - *- coding: utf- 8 - *- on the first line solved the problem.

```
- *- coding: utf- 8 - *-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.krak.dk/cafe/søg.cs?consumer=suggest?search_word=cafe"
r = requests.get(url).content 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html5lib')
```